# PSTricks: Partitioning and filling a circle in pst-pdgr

Tags: pstricks, circles

I am using the [`pst-pdgr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-pdgr) package which uses PSTricks to generate medical pedigrees. I find this package to be very useful, however I ran into a problem with a certain situation I am having. I need a node (Person) to be divided into four segments rather than 2 (which is possible by setting `condition=asymptotic`) and each quadrant should be able to be filled or not. Is this possible with some package or manipulation of the pst-pdgr package?

For instance, I need a node partitioned into multiple sections like in Figure 1 of http://www.gghjournal.com/pdf/volume_11/11-3/ab8.pdf, where the circle and diamond are partitioned in the affected individual portion (although with the circle the sectioning should be like a plus sign (`+`), not like the diamond).

For example, the documentation provides code for this pedigree, with John having a partition of 2, where I need 4 (and preferably 3 as well). In addition, I should have the ability to fill in any section I want.

```
\psset{descarmA=1}
\rput(0.5,2){\pstPerson[male, belowtext=Fred]{A}}
\rput(2.5,2){\pstPerson[female, obligatory, belowtext=Ginger]{B}}
\pstRelationship[descentnode=AB]{A}{B}
\rput(0.5,0.5){\pstPerson[male,asymptomatic, belowtext=John]{C1}}
\rput(1.5,0.5){\pstPerson[female,belowtext=Mary]{C2}}
\rput(2.5,0.5){\pstAbortion[sab, affected, belowtext=male]{C3}}
\pstDescent{AB}{C1}
\pstDescent{AB}{C2}
\pstDescent{AB}{C3}
```

An example for the missing symbols is below:
[image: Affected individual]
[image: Asymptomatic/presymptomatic]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 3):

This is the option I planned to add  for a long time.  However, since nobody requested it, I never got around to implement is.  Now somebody (you) did :)

A question, by the way, for which I do not know the answer.  Suppose a person has four conditions, and is asymptomatic for one of them.  I should divide the symbol into four sectors, right?  How do I show the asymptomatic character of one?  By dividing the sector?

Comment: This package is incredibly useful (thank you for this! :) ) and contains the vast majority of situations. However, to be useful in clinical practice in this situation I would just need the addition of the affected individual with greater than or equal to conditions shown in the below paper (Figure 1 part 2 bottom half with the circle and square) as well as the solid bold vertical line seen with asymptomatic/presymptomatic carrier in Figure 4 part 3. This paper is pretty much the standard for now so unless more discoveries take place, this package is almost feature complete!

Comment: The article is: Bennett R. et al.Standardized Human Pedigree Nomenclature: Update and Assessment of the Recommendations of the National Society of Genetic Counselors. (2008) J Genetic Counseling 17:424-433

(I would post pictures if I had a higher reputation in this site).

Comment: I actually now have the reputation, so I posted the pictures from the citation in the original question.